# isSingleton attribute for FactoryBean

Tags: spring

I am trying to create a FactoryBean to instantiate an object. I want this object to be then treated  as singleton by Spring.

My factory bean implementation itself will not ensure that the object it returns on getObject will always be singleton. It will simply return a new object every time  getObject() is called.

As per the documentation for the `isSingleton` method, "Is the object managed by this factory a singleton? That is, will `getObject()` always return the same object (a reference that can be cached)? If a `FactoryBean`  indicates to hold a singleton object, the object returned from `getObject()` might get cached by the owning `BeanFactory`. Hence, do not return `true` unless the `FactoryBean` always exposes the same reference."

If I want to enforce the resulting object from `FactoryBean` to be singleton, should I set `isSingleton` to be `true` ? Wouldn't it conflict with the definition which says "Hence, do not return `true` unless the `FactoryBean` always exposes the same reference" ?

Sample FactoryBean

```
public class SampleFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<SampleObject> {

    
    @Override
    public SampleObject getObject() throws Exception {
        return new SampleObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SampleObject.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear.

Comment: @NathanHughes Apologies, can you clarify your comment. Do you mean to say that yes, one should set isSingleton to true only if the custom FactoryBean implementation ensures that it will always return the same instance on call to getObject. 

If yes, how can I use Spring to ensure that a singleton instance of SampleObject is created. Thanks.

Comment: That is  what the documentation states. If you want it to be a singleton make it a singleton in the factorbean. If it isn't and returns a new object each time `getObject` is returned it simply isn't a singleton. There is nothing prevent you from injecting the `FactoryBean` and call `getObject` if you don't guard the creation of the object (cache it yourself) it will create different instances (Spring won't help you there).